# Сброс внешнего вида QScrollarea

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qss, qscrollbar

Чем вызван сброс внешнего вида `QScrollarea` и его возвращением после входа в раздел `styleSheet` и нажатия на кнопку **`ок`**. 
**`UI`** приложение: [здесь](https://gitlab.com/strtz57/file-educ5.ui/-/blob/main/educ5.ui).

А после конвертирования так вообще не отображается.

То как это должно выглядеть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И то как это выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и непосредственно сам код

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Enrollee(object):
    def setupUi(self, Enrollee):
        Enrollee.setObjectName("Enrollee")
        Enrollee.resize(450, 800)
        Enrollee.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ffffff;")
        self.WidgetsEnrollee = QtWidgets.QWidget(Enrollee)
        self.WidgetsEnrollee.setObjectName("WidgetsEnrollee")
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.WidgetsEnrollee)
        self.scrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(15, 85, 435, 705))
        self.scrollArea.setStyleSheet("QScrollArea {\n"
"    border: 0px solid ;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar:horizontal {\n"
"    border-radius: 10;\n"
"    border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;\n"
"    background: #595959;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::handle:horizontal {\n"
"    border-radius: 8;\n"
"    background: #ffffff;\n"
"    min-width: 20px;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal {\n"
"    border: none;\n"
"    background: none;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal{\n"
"    background: none;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QScrollBar:vertical {\n"
"    border-radius: 10;\n"
"    border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;\n"
"    background: #595959;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::handle:vertical {\n"
"    border-radius: 8;\n"
"    background: #ffffff;\n"
"    min-width: 20px;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-line:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {\n"
"    border: none;\n"
"    background: none;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical{\n"
"    background: none;\n"
"}")
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.WidgetsScrollArea = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.WidgetsScrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 414, 725))
        self.WidgetsScrollArea.setStyleSheet("")
        self.WidgetsScrollArea.setObjectName("WidgetsScrollArea")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.WidgetsScrollArea)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 14, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.WidgetsFrame = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.WidgetsScrollArea)
        self.WidgetsFrame.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 725))
        self.WidgetsFrame.setObjectName("WidgetsFrame")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.WidgetsFrame)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 15, 400, 705))
        self.frame.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.frame.setFont(font)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ffffff;\n"
"border-radius: 10;\n"
"border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;\n"
"color: #000000;")
        self.frame.setText("")
        self.frame.setIndent(0)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.math = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.WidgetsFrame)
        self.math.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 0, 70, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.math.setFont(font)
        self.math.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 10;\n"
"border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;\n"
"color: #000000;")
        self.math.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.math.setIndent(0)
        self.math.setObjectName("math")
        self.ukrain = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.WidgetsFrame)
        self.ukrain.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(325, 0, 70, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.ukrain.setFont(font)
        self.ukrain.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 10;\n"
"border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;\n"
"color: #000000;")
        self.ukrain.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.ukrain.setIndent(0)
        self.ukrain.setObjectName("ukrain")
        self.num = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.WidgetsFrame)
        self.num.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 45, 30, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.num.setFont(font)
        self.num.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;\n"
"color: #000000;")
        self.num.setText("")
        self.num.setIndent(10)
        self.num.setObjectName("num")
        self.name = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.WidgetsFrame)
        self.name.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(28, 45, 222, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.name.setFont(font)
        self.name.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;\n"
"color: #000000;")
        self.name.setText("")
        self.name.setIndent(10)
        self.name.setObjectName("name")
        self.grade_math = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.WidgetsFrame)
        self.grade_math.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(248, 45, 77, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.grade_math.setFont(font)
        self.grade_math.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;\n"
"color: #000000;")
        self.grade_math.setText("")
        self.grade_math.setIndent(10)
        self.grade_math.setObjectName("grade_math")
        self.grade_ukrain = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.WidgetsFrame)
        self.grade_ukrain.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(323, 45, 77, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.grade_ukrain.setFont(font)
        self.grade_ukrain.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;\n"
"color: #000000;")
        self.grade_ukrain.setText("")
        self.grade_ukrain.setIndent(10)
        self.grade_ukrain.setObjectName("grade_ukrain")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.WidgetsFrame)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.WidgetsScrollArea)
        self.ninth_grade = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.WidgetsEnrollee)
        self.ninth_grade.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(45, 20, 180, 45))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.ninth_grade.setFont(font)
        self.ninth_grade.setStyleSheet("background-color: #363636;\n"
"border-radius: 22;\n"
"color: #ffffff;\n"
"")
        self.ninth_grade.setObjectName("ninth_grade")
        self.eleventh_grade = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.WidgetsEnrollee)
        self.eleventh_grade.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(225, 20, 180, 45))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.eleventh_grade.setFont(font)
        self.eleventh_grade.setStyleSheet("background-color: #595959;\n"
"border-radius: 22;\n"
"color: #ffffff;")
        self.eleventh_grade.setObjectName("eleventh_grade")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.WidgetsEnrollee)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(45, 20, 360, 45))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: #595959;\n"
"border-radius: 22;\n"
"color: #ffffff;")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label.raise_()
        self.scrollArea.raise_()
        self.ninth_grade.raise_()
        self.eleventh_grade.raise_()
        Enrollee.setCentralWidget(self.WidgetsEnrollee)

        self.retranslateUi(Enrollee)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Enrollee)

    def retranslateUi(self, Enrollee):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Enrollee.setWindowTitle(_translate("Enrollee", "MainWindow"))
        self.math.setText(_translate("Enrollee", "МАТ"))
        self.ukrain.setText(_translate("Enrollee", "УКР.ЯЗ"))
        self.ninth_grade.setText(_translate("Enrollee", "9 КЛАСС"))
        self.eleventh_grade.setText(_translate("Enrollee", "11 КЛАСС"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Enrollee = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Enrollee()
    ui.setupUi(Enrollee)
    Enrollee.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pyqt5-qscrollbar-getting-style-sheet/

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html

Comment: @AlexanderChernin я скорее всего не корректно задал вопрос., я использовал таблицу стилей в Qt Designer но при конвертировании в код изменения не отображается при запуске программы, да и в Qt Designer работает через раз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не совсем понимаю структуру вашей формы и не проверял ваш *StyleSheet* для `QScrollBar`.

Я просто вставил свой *StyleSheet* в виджет `WidgetsEnrollee` и все.

Выполните **`pyuic5 educ5.ui -o q1369689_ui.py -x`** 
и запускайте хоть **q1369689_ui.py**, хоть **q1369689_main.py**.

---

**educ5.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Enrollee</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="Enrollee">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>481</width>
    <height>645</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background-color: #ffffff;</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="WidgetsEnrollee">
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">/* VERTICAL SCROLLBAR */
QScrollBar:vertical {
    border: none;
    background: rgb(45, 45, 68);
    width: 14px;
    margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

/*  HANDLE BAR VERTICAL */
QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
    background-color: rgb(80, 80, 122);
    min-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical:hover{
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical:pressed {
    background-color: rgb(185, 0, 92);
}

/* BTN TOP - SCROLLBAR */
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    border: none;
    background-color: rgb(59, 59, 90);
    height: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:hover { 
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:pressed {
    background-color: rgb(185, 0, 92);
}

/* BTN BOTTOM - SCROLLBAR */
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
    border: none;
    background-color: rgb(59, 59, 90);
    height: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:hover { 
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:pressed { 
    background-color: rgb(185, 0, 92);
}

/* RESET ARROW */
QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical {
    background: none;
}
QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {
    background: none;
}

/* HORIZONTAL SCROLLBAR - HOMEWORK */
QScrollBar:horizontal {
}
QScrollBar::handle:horizontal {
}
QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal {
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal {
}
QScrollBar::up-arrow:horizontal, QScrollBar::down-arrow:horizontal
{
}
QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal
{
} </string>
   </property>
   <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>15</x>
      <y>85</y>
      <width>435</width>
      <height>705</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="widgetResizable">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="WidgetsScrollArea">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>0</x>
       <y>0</y>
       <width>419</width>
       <height>725</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true"/>
     </property>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
      <property name="spacing">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="leftMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="topMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="rightMargin">
       <number>14</number>
      </property>
      <property name="bottomMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <item>
       <widget class="QWidget" name="WidgetsFrame" native="true">
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>400</width>
          <height>725</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true"/>
        </property>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="frame">
         <property name="geometry">
          <rect>
           <x>0</x>
           <y>15</y>
           <width>400</width>
           <height>705</height>
          </rect>
         </property>
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>0</width>
           <height>0</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <family>Montserrat</family>
           <pointsize>9</pointsize>
           <weight>75</weight>
           <bold>true</bold>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">background-color: #fff;
border-radius: 10;
border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;
color: #000000;
</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string/>
         </property>
         <property name="indent">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="math">
         <property name="geometry">
          <rect>
           <x>250</x>
           <y>0</y>
           <width>70</width>
           <height>30</height>
          </rect>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <family>Montserrat</family>
           <pointsize>9</pointsize>
           <weight>75</weight>
           <bold>true</bold>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">border-radius: 10;
border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;
color: #000000;</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>МАТ</string>
         </property>
         <property name="alignment">
          <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
         </property>
         <property name="indent">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="ukrain">
         <property name="geometry">
          <rect>
           <x>325</x>
           <y>0</y>
           <width>70</width>
           <height>30</height>
          </rect>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <family>Montserrat</family>
           <pointsize>9</pointsize>
           <weight>75</weight>
           <bold>true</bold>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">border-radius: 10;
border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;
color: #000000;</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>УКР.ЯЗ</string>
         </property>
         <property name="alignment">
          <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
         </property>
         <property name="indent">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="num">
         <property name="geometry">
          <rect>
           <x>0</x>
           <y>45</y>
           <width>30</width>
           <height>30</height>
          </rect>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <family>Montserrat</family>
           <pointsize>9</pointsize>
           <weight>75</weight>
           <bold>true</bold>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;
color: #000000;</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string/>
         </property>
         <property name="indent">
          <number>10</number>
         </property>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="name">
         <property name="geometry">
          <rect>
           <x>28</x>
           <y>45</y>
           <width>222</width>
           <height>30</height>
          </rect>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <family>Montserrat</family>
           <pointsize>9</pointsize>
           <weight>75</weight>
           <bold>true</bold>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;
color: #000000;</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string/>
         </property>
         <property name="indent">
          <number>10</number>
         </property>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="grade_math">
         <property name="geometry">
          <rect>
           <x>248</x>
           <y>45</y>
           <width>77</width>
           <height>30</height>
          </rect>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <family>Montserrat</family>
           <pointsize>9</pointsize>
           <weight>75</weight>
           <bold>true</bold>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;
color: #000000;</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string/>
         </property>
         <property name="indent">
          <number>10</number>
         </property>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="grade_ukrain">
         <property name="geometry">
          <rect>
           <x>323</x>
           <y>45</y>
           <width>77</width>
           <height>30</height>
          </rect>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <family>Montserrat</family>
           <pointsize>9</pointsize>
           <weight>75</weight>
           <bold>true</bold>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;
color: #000000;</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string/>
         </property>
         <property name="indent">
          <number>10</number>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="ninth_grade">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>45</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>180</width>
      <height>45</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Montserrat</family>
      <pointsize>9</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-color: #363636;
border-radius: 22;
color: #ffffff;
</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>9 КЛАСС</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="eleventh_grade">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>225</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>180</width>
      <height>45</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Montserrat</family>
      <pointsize>9</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-color: #595959;
border-radius: 22;
color: #ffffff;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>11 КЛАСС</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>45</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>360</width>
      <height>45</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-color: #595959;
border-radius: 22;
color: #ffffff;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <zorder>label</zorder>
   <zorder>scrollArea</zorder>
   <zorder>ninth_grade</zorder>
   <zorder>eleventh_grade</zorder>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

---

**q1369689_main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from q1369689_ui import Ui_Enrollee


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Enrollee):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self) 
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это действительно сработало, когда я вставил свой `StyleSheet` в виджет `WidgetsEnrollee` то при запуске кода стали видны изменения `QScrollBar`, но почему тогда когда я вставил StyleSheet в `QScrollArea` то изменения были видны только в QtDesigner